# How to use .so file from one project to another

Tags: android, dll, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I'm trying to link some `.so` that I generated using the NDK to a new `.so` I'm trying to create, as the old `.so` contains definitions of functions that I want to use in the new `.so`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using something like this in your `Android.mk` should do it:

```
# Use the sub library as a prebuilt shared library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := MySubLibrary
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /path/to/sub/library.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := /path/to/sub/library/includes
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Build your own library referencing your sub library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := MyFinalLibrary
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := MySubLibrary
# Add your source files etc here...
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i am able to generate two .so file in libs folder.so which one i should select to use in system.loadlibrary("");command.

Comment: You'll have to add both of them. When using dynamic libraries (`.so` files), the idea is that one library can reference another one, but both must exist as independent libraries.